# Using weights initializer with tf.nn.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, initializer

When using `tf.layers.conv2d`, setting the initializer is easy, it can be done through its parameter. But what if I use `tf.nn.conv2d`? I use this code. Is this equivalent to setting the `kernel_initializer` parameter in `tf.layers.conv2d`? Although the program runs without errors, I don't know how to verify whether it does what it is expected do.

```
 with tf.name_scope('conv1_2') as scope:
        kernel = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), 
                                 shape=[3, 3, 32, 32], name='weights')
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[32], dtype=tf.float32),
                             trainable=True, name='biases')
        out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        self.conv1_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
        self.parameters += [kernel, biases]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation underneath is the same (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785026/tf-nn-conv2d-vs-tf-layers-conv2d)).

As for the kernel and its initialization, I took a glimpse in the code and it *looked* the same... the `layers.conv2d` call a `tf.get_variable` at the end of the day.

But I wanted to see it empirically, so here is a test code that declares a conv2d using each method (`tf.layers.conv2d` and `tf.nn.conv2d`), evaluates the initialized kernels and compares them.

I've arbitrarily set the things that shouldn't interfere in the comparison, such as an input tensor and the strides.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# the way you described in your question
def _nn(input_tensor, initializer, filters, size):
    kernel = tf.get_variable(
        initializer=initializer, 
        shape=[size, size, 32, filters],
        name='kernel')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
        input=input_tensor,
        filter=kernel,
        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding='SAME')

    return kernel

# the other way
def _layer(input_tensor, initializer, filters, size):
    tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_tensor,
        filters=filters,
        kernel_size=size,
        kernel_initializer=initializer)

    # 'conv2d/kernel:0' is the name of the generated kernel
    return tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('conv2d/kernel:0')

def _get_kernel(method):
    # an isolated context for each conv2d
    graph = tf.Graph()
    sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)

    with graph.as_default(), sess.as_default():
        # important so that same randomness doesnt play a role
        tf.set_random_seed(42)

        # arbitrary input tensor with compatible shape
        input_tensor = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1, 64, 64, 32])

        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()

        kernel = method(
            input_tensor=input_tensor,
            initializer=initializer,
            filters=32,
            size=3)

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        return sess.run(kernel)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kernel_nn = _get_kernel(_nn)
    kernel_layer = _get_kernel(_layer)

    print('kernels are ', end='')
    # compares shape and values
    if np.array_equal(kernel_layer, kernel_nn):
        print('exactly the same')
    else:
        print('not the same!')
```

And the output is... **kernels are exactly the same**.

The docs, btw: [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) and [tf.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d).