# Switching from tf.contrib.layers.conv2d to tf.nn.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d` so far, but (e.g. to allow for weight decay filters as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785026/tf-nn-conv2d-vs-tf-layers-conv2d)) I want to switch to the `tf.nn.conv2d` implementation. However I am confused regarding the parameters, since apparently I need to specify things that before I haven't.

With doc and SO entries I gave it a try. For 4D-Tensors with [batch_size, x, y, channels], **are these two versions identical?** I.e. am I correct in assuming that input_layer.shape[-1] represents the `input_channels` as required in `filter` and that I have to explicitly set strides to the number of dims of my input tensor:

*with tf.contrib.layers.conv2d  (original)*

```
down0a = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(input_layer, n_features, (3, 3))
down0b = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(down0a, n_features, (3, 3))
down0c = tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d(down0b_do, (2, 2), padding='same')
```

*with tf.nn.conv2d*

```
down0a = tf.nn.conv2d(input_layer, filter=[3, 3, input_layer.shape[-1], n_features], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
down0ar = tf.nn.relu(down0a)
down0b = tf.nn.conv2d(down0ar, filter=[3, 3, down0ar.shape[-1], n_features], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
down0br = tf.nn.relu(down0b)
down0c = tf.nn.max_pool(down0br, [2, 2, down0br.shape[-1], n_features], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have gotten the shapes correct, the most obvious issue appears to be that you aren't supposed to tell `tf.nn.conv2d` the shapes, you're supposed to pass it the actual weight tensor.

```
down0w = tf.get_variable("down0w", shape=[3, 3, input_layer.shape[-1], n_features], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
down0a = tf.nn.conv2d(input_layer, filter=down0w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```