# Inequivalent output from tf.nn.conv2d and keras.layers.Conv2D

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, keras, equivalent

I've been reading the *Hands-On Machine Learning* textbook (2nd edition) by Aurélien Géron ([textbook publisher webpage here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/)). I've gotten into the content that applies CNNs to images. In the section titled *Tensorflow Implementation* of Chapter 14, they manually create filters that get passed to `tf.nn.conv2d` and applied to an image to produce a set of feature maps. After these manual filter examples, the book says:

> in a real CNN you would normally define filters as trainable variables ... Instead of manually creating the variables, use the `keras.layers.Conv2D` layer.

The above quote implies to me that given identical inputs (and equivalent initializations), we should be able to derive identical outputs from `tf.nn.conv2d` and `keras.layers.Conv2D`. To validate this idea, I looked up whether the two functions were equivalent. According to [this previously answered SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785026/tf-nn-conv2d-vs-tf-layers-conv2d), **for convolution, the two functions are the same**.

I set out to perform a simple test of their equivalence. I created a convolutional layer consisting of one feature map using a 7x7 filter (a.k.a: *convolutional kernel*) **of all zeros** that was implemented separately for `tf.nn.conv2d` and `keras.layers.Conv2D`. As expected, after summing all the pixel values in the difference of both images, this filter did cause the output images to have a value of zero for each pixel value. This difference of zero implies that the output images are identical.

I then decided to create the same 7x7 filter, but **with all ones** this time. Ideally, both functions should produce the same output, therefore the difference in the two output images should be zero. Unfortunately, when I check the difference in the output images (and sum the differences at each pixel), I get a nonzero sum value. Upon plotting the images and their difference, it is evident that they are not the same image (though they do look *very* similar at a glance).

After reading through the documentation for both functions, I believe that I am giving them equivalent inputs. **What could I be doing/assuming incorrectly that is preventing both functions from producing identical outputs?**

I have attached my code and versionining information below for reference. The code uses the scikit-learn `china.jpg` sample image as input and `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` to help in visualizing the output images and their difference.

> TF Version: 2.2.0-dev20200229
>
> Keras Version: 2.3.1
>
> Scikit-Learn Version: 0.22.1
>
> Matplotlib Version: 3.1.3
>
> Numpy Version: 1.18.1

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# Get the feature map as a result of tf.nn.conv2d
def featureMap1(batch):
    
    # Extract the channels
    batch_size, height, width, channels = batch.shape

    # Make a (7,7,3,1) filter set (one set of a 7x7 filter per channel)
    # of just ones. 
    filters = np.ones(shape=(7, 7, channels, 1), dtype=np.float32)

    # Run the conv2d with stride of 1 (i.e: in.shape = out.shape)
    # Generate one feature map for this conv layer
    fmaps = tf.nn.conv2d(batch, filters,
                         strides=1, padding='SAME',
                         data_format='NHWC')
    
    # Return the feature map
    return fmaps

# Get the feature map as a result of keras.layers.Conv2D
def featureMap2(batch):

    # Create the input layer with the shape of the images
    inputLayer = keras.layers.Input(shape=batch.shape[1:])
    
    # Create the convLayer which should apply the filter of all ones
    convLayer = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=7,
                                    strides=1, padding='SAME',
                                    kernel_initializer='ones',
                                    data_format='channels_last',
                                    activation='linear')

    # Create the ouput layer
    outputLayer = convLayer(inputLayer)

    # Set up the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputLayer,
                        outputs=outputLayer)

    # Perform a prediction, no model fitting or compiling
    fmaps = model.predict(batch)

    return fmaps 

def main():

    # Get the image and scale the RGB values to [0, 1]
    china = load_sample_image('china.jpg') / 255

    # Build a batch of just one image
    batch = np.array([china])

    # Get the feature maps and extract
    # the images within them
    img1 = featureMap1(batch)[0, :, :, 0]
    img2 = featureMap2(batch)[0, :, :, 0]

    # Calculate the difference in the images
    # Ideally, this should be all zeros...
    diffImage = np.abs(img1 - img2)

    # Add up all the pixels in the diffImage,
    # we expect a value of 0 if the images are
    # identical
    print('Differences value: ', diffImage.sum())

    # Plot the images as a set of 4
    figsize = 10
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(figsize,figsize))

    axarr[0,0].set_title('Original Image')
    axarr[0,0].imshow(batch[0], cmap='gray')

    axarr[1,0].set_title('Conv2D through tf.nn.conv2d')
    axarr[1,0].imshow(img1, cmap='gray')
    
    axarr[1,1].set_title('Conv2D through keras.layers.Conv2D')
    axarr[1,1].imshow(img2, cmap='gray')

    axarr[0,1].set_title('Diff')
    axarr[0,1].imshow(diffImage, cmap='gray')
    
    plt.show()
    
    return


main()
```

Comment: How large are the differences? Are they really significant? AFAIK there is some randomness associated with certain CUDA operations. Can you try applying the _same_ method twice and see whether this gives different results between both runs?

Comment: I just took the difference between images run through the same function, and their  difference *is* exactly 0. This tells me that randomness may not play a factor.

Comment: @xdurch0 I have also noticed that the nonzero differences value that the above code prints out is the same across multiple runs of the code. This further indicates that randomness may not be a significant factor in the outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the two Convolutional Layers should be identical.

You are comparing a **Model** to an **Operation**, whereas you should compare **Operation** (tf.keras.Conv2D) to **Operation** (tf.nn.conv2d).

Modified the **featureMap2** function.

```
def featureMap2(batch):
    # Create the convLayer which should apply the filter of all ones
    convLayer = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size = 7,
                                    strides=1, padding='SAME',
                                    kernel_initializer='ones',
                                    data_format='channels_last',
                                    activation='linear')
    fmaps = convLayer(batch)
    return fmaps
```

Here are the plots generated.

[image: conv2d_plots]

Here is the full modified code snippet execute in **Google Colab Environment** with added **Seed** just to ensure reproducibility and commented out previous code.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(26)
np.random.seed(26)
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')


# Get the feature map as a result of tf.nn.conv2d
def featureMap1(batch):

    # Extract the channels
    batch_size, height, width, channels = batch.shape

    # Make a (7,7,3,1) filter set (one set of a 7x7 filter per channel)
    # of just ones. 
    filters = np.ones(shape=(7, 7, channels, 1), dtype=np.float32)

    # Run the conv2d with stride of 1 (i.e: in.shape = out.shape)
    # Generate one feature map for this conv layer
    fmaps = tf.nn.conv2d(batch, filters,
                         strides=1, padding='SAME',
                         data_format='NHWC')

    # Return the feature map
    return fmaps

# Get the feature map as a result of keras.layers.Conv2D
def featureMap2(batch):

    # Create the convLayer which should apply the filter of all ones
    convLayer = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size = 7,
                                    strides=1, padding='SAME',
                                    kernel_initializer='ones',
                                    data_format='channels_last',
                                    activation='linear')

    fmaps = convLayer(batch)

    # Create the ouput layer
    # outputLayer = convLayer(inputLayer)

    # # Set up the model
    # model = keras.Model(inputs=inputLayer,
    #                     outputs=outputLayer)

    # Perform a prediction, no model fitting or compiling
    # fmaps = model.predict(batch)

    return fmaps 

def main():

    # Get the image and scale the RGB values to [0, 1]
    china = load_sample_image('china.jpg') / 255

    # Build a batch of just one image
    batch = np.array([china])

    # Get the feature maps and extract
    # the images within them
    img1 = featureMap1(batch)[0, :, :, 0]
    img2 = featureMap2(batch)[0, :, :, 0]
    # Calculate the difference in the images
    # Ideally, this should be all zeros...
    diffImage = np.abs(img1 - img2)

    # Add up all the pixels in the diffImage,
    # we expect a value of 0 if the images are
    # identical
    print('Differences value: ', diffImage.sum())

    # Plot the images as a set of 4
    figsize = 10
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(figsize,figsize))

    axarr[0,0].set_title('Original Image')
    axarr[0,0].imshow(batch[0], cmap='gray')

    axarr[1,0].set_title('Conv2D through tf.nn.conv2d')
    axarr[1,0].imshow(img1, cmap='gray')

    axarr[1,1].set_title('Conv2D through keras.layers.Conv2D')
    axarr[1,1].imshow(img2, cmap='gray')

    axarr[0,1].set_title('Diff')
    axarr[0,1].imshow(diffImage, cmap='gray')

    plt.show()

    return


main()
```

**EDIT:**

The main culprit was the **Default Casting** behavior of **TensorFlow 2.x**.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer conv2d is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 2.  The layer has dtype float32 because it's dtype defaults to floatx.
```

This reduces the accuracy of the computation due to **precision loss** from `float64` to `float32`. 
You can avoid having this precision loss by **setting the Tensorflow Keras Backend** default **floatx** to **float64**.

```
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain where in the ***Model***-based approach it could be perturbing the image?

Comment: Hi @Greg, I already updated the answer due to **casting behavior** that made the layers and model produce **different results**. But you should always compare **Operations to Operations** when comparing **independent operations**.

Comment: Understood. From your insight, I tried to set all the original question code dytpe arguments (on layers, conv2d calls, and image importing) to `float32`. With this I was able to get the desired results. I also tried adding the `set_floatx` line to the original code and can note that the desired behavior also ensues. I'll keep in mind the casting behavior and datatype consistency for future TF work. Thank you!